# Handling Unknown Errors in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, exception, protractor

I have a `protractor` setup with multiple browsers configured through `multiCapabilities`, running tests on browserstack.

One of my key protractor specs/tests contain the following `afterEach()` block:

```
afterEach(function() {
    browser.manage().logs().get("browser").then(function (browserLog) {
        expect(browserLog.length).toEqual(0);
    });
});
```

that checks that the browser console is empty (no errors on the console).

**The problem is**: when I run this spec against Internet Explorer, I'm getting an `UnknownError`:

> UnknownError: Command not found: POST /session/6b838fe8-f4a6-4b31-b245-f4bf8f37537c/log

After a quick research, I've found out that `IE selenium webdriver` does not yet support session logs:

- [[IE] Add support for fetching logs using the webdriver.manage().logs() mechanism](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4925)

**The question is:** how can I catch this `UnknownError` and let the spec pass in case of this specific error?

Or, to turn it around, is it possible to have an `afterEach()` block capability/browser-specific, or know which currently running capability is it?

---

I've tried to use `try/catch` and try relying on exception `sender`, but `console.log()` is not executed:

```
afterEach(function() {
    try {
        browser.manage().logs().get("browser").then(function (browserLog) {
            expect(browserLog.length).toEqual(0);
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.sender);
    }
});
```

As a workaround, I'm duplicating the same spec but without that failing `afterEach()` block, specifically for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found one option - using [`getCapabilities()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCapabilities) to retrieve the current browser name:

```
afterEach(function() {
    browser.driver.getCapabilities().then(function(caps) {
        var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName;

        if (browserName !== "internet explorer") {
            browser.manage().logs().get("browser").then(function (browserLog) {
                expect(browserLog.length).toEqual(0);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In this case browser logs would not be checked if running against Internet Explorer.