# is there a getConfig() for Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I've the following `config.js` file:

```
var testName = 'Testing';
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
    docTitle: 'Report Test Summary',
    docName: 'protractor-tests-report.html'
});
exports.config = {

    seleniumAddress: 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub',
    multiCapabilities: [

        {
            name: testName,
            browserName: 'Chrome',
            browser_version: '39.0',
            os: 'OS X',
            os_version: 'Yosemite',
            resolution: '1920x1080',
            'browserstack.user': browserstackUser,
            'browserstack.key': browserstackKey,
            'browserstack.debug': 'true',
            'browserstack.selenium_version': '2.45.0'
        }
        ,
        {
            name: testName,
            browserName: 'IE',
            browser_version: '11.0',
            os: 'Windows',
            os_version: '8.1',
            resolution: '2048x1536',
            'browserstack.user': browserstackUser,
            'browserstack.key': browserstackKey,
            'browserstack.debug': 'true',
            'browserstack.selenium_version': '2.45.0',
            'browserstack.ie.driver': '2.44',
            //ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true
        }
    ],

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
    // protractor is called.

    suites: {
        waitlist: './././specs/waitlist_page_spec.js',
        press: './././specs/press_page_spec.js',
        news: './././specs/news_page_spec.js',
        landing: './././specs/landing_page_spec.js'
    },


    // Maximum number of total browser sessions to run. Tests are queued in
    // sequence if number of browser sessions is limited by this parameter.
    // Use a number less than 1 to denote unlimited. Default is unlimited.
    maxSessions: 2,

    // protractor will save the test output in json format at this path.
    // The path is relative to the location of this config.
    resultJsonOutputFile: null,

    framework: 'jasmine2',

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000,
        realtimeFailure: true,
        showTiming: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        onComplete: null
    },

    onPrepare: function () {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        global.dvr = browser.driver; //variable to call selenium directly
        global.isAngularSite = function (flag) {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = !flag; //This setup is to configure when testing non-angular pages
        };
        //browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90000);
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100000);

    }

};
```

And I would like to find a way to ask on my test that if the capability.browserName is IE do a certain/especial action, so, I would like to do some sort of getConfig(), is that possible? does anyone had implemented something similar?

Thanks all for your time!

Comment: See also these related threads:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587571/handling-unknown-errors-in-protractor and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872955/get-the-current-browser-name-in-protractor-test.

Comment: What Am I doing Wrong here?
it('User should see a message that he has already been added to the campaing when entering the same email twice', function () {
browser.driver.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName;
if (browserName == "IE") {
console.log('IE avoided');
} else {basePage.email.sendKeys('bruno@test.com');
basePage.subscribe.click().then(function () {
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(basePage.confirmationMessage), 100000);
basePage.confirmMessage('Contact already added to target campaign');
});
            }
        });
    });

Comment: It does not avoid IE for that particular test... it's like it's going always thru the else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getCapabilities in browser returns a promise with these values:

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (capabilities) {
    browser = capabilities.caps_.browserName;
    platform = capabilities.caps_.platform;
}).then(function displayEnv() {
    console.log('Browser:', browser, 'on platform', platform);
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! this is what I've done to make it work!    it('User should ', function () {
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (capabilities) {
browser = capabilities.caps_.browserName;
}).then(function () {
console.log('Browser:', browser, 'on platform', platform);
if (browser == 'internet explorer') {
console.log('IE Was avoided for this test.');} else {basePage.email.sendKeys('bruno@test.com');
console.log('Mande el mail');
basePage.subscribe.click().then(function () {
                    basePage.confirmMessage('Contact already added to target campaign');
});}}) });